# In wordpress how to change permalink structure of custom type from test.com/movies/%name% to test.com/movies/%name%/%year%

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site on wordpress with a custom post type: Movies. In this custom post type I can define the name of the movie and the year of the movie.

Currently my permalinks are:

`test.com/movies/%name%`

But I want them to be:

`test.com/movies/%name%/%year%`

How can I define or overwrite the permalink structure?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please check it - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161548/change-the-custom-post-type-permalink

Comment: Thanks for your comment, sadly is not what I'm looking. I get that with register_post_type('movies', ['rewrite' => ['slug' => 'movies']]) I could get the permalink to "movies" but how can I define that the permalink also includes the year? I have tried setting 'slug' to 'movies/%movie_year%' but the permalink looks like 'movies/%movie_year%/matrix' not 'movies/matrix/1999'.